# Azure Functions returns same data if input data is same between two calls

Tags: c#, azure-functions

i have come across a strange problem.

have an excel sheet with 5 columns. then i append data from the 5 columns into a query string and in a certain cell i call an Azure Function API which returns a string.

the problem i am facing is the if the data is different in the excel then i get unique/ different data from the az function. but my data can be the same too.

the logic in the web service is that it simply creates a new database record and return the unique id for the record.

so the question is why does is return the same data when we make multiple parallel call with same data. interestingly, new database records are created but possibly cached data is returned.

i have tried to add the following

```
var response = req.CreateResponse();
response.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
.....
.....
string RedirectURL = new Helper().GetRedirectURL(CampaignUser.TrackingId);

response.WriteString(RedirectURL);
return response;
```

"CampaignUser.TrackingId" is unique but I am getting the same value in all calls?

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

***You can implement below code to prevent caching:-***

I have created a sample Function App and Console app to resolve your issue by preventing caching like below:-

**My console app:-**

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Replace "YourAzureFunctionUrl" with the actual URL of your Azure Function
        string functionUrl = "https://valleyfunc764.azurewebsites.net/api/CallFunctionFromConsoleApp?code=vCNUSQVORzxFNCYrHVbtjHnjfEyI7ia2rpw3KJOcF_zYAzFukSDIKA==&param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param4=value4&param5=value5";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Prevent caching by adding appropriate headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(functionUrl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Response from Azure Function: " + responseContent);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error calling Azure Function. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***My Function Trigger code:-***

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class CallAzureFunctionFromConsoleApp
{
    [FunctionName("CallFunctionFromConsoleApp")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

      
        string param1 = req.Query["param1"];
        string param2 = req.Query["param2"];
        string param3 = req.Query["param3"];
        string param4 = req.Query["param4"];
        string param5 = req.Query["param5"];
        string result = $"{param1} {param2} {param3} {param4} {param5}";

        return new OkObjectResult(result);
    }
}
```

```http
https://valleyfunc764.azurewebsites.net/api/CallFunctionFromConsoleApp?code=xxxxxxxxxxrpw3KJOcF_zYAzFukSDIKA==&param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param4=value4&param5=value5
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am sure this take care of the problem when I am using a client like console app, web app etc. But the problem I ma facing is how do I set the headers when using the "webservice" excel function.